# How to move two parenting objects together?

Tags: parent

When I try to move two objects together they move separatelly in a weird way, here is a [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yWPU.jpg) showing what happens.

How can I solve this?

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *Proportional editing* enabled.
When you move your object, all near objects move in the same direction.

It has nothing to do with parenting.

Disable it, and all goes back to normal.
[image]